# Is introducing reference to DI container inside main ViewModel a design flaw?

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection

I have the following

- **ViewModels:** `MainWindowViewModel`, `BaseProjectViewModel`, `TextFileProjectViewModel`, `SpreadsheetProjectViewModel`
  (TextFileProjectViewModel, SpreadsheetProjectViewModel inherit from BaseProjectViewModel)
- **Services:**

  `FileDIalogService : IFileDialogService`
  `MessageBoxService : IMessageBoxService`
  `ModalDialogFactory : IModalDialogFactory`
  `ModalDialogService : IModalDialogservice`

MainWindowViewModel has the following constructor:

```
public MainWindowViewModel( IModalDialogService     modalDialogService,
                            IModalDialogFactory     modalDialogFactory,
                            IMessageBoxService      messageBoxService,
                            IFileDialogService      fileDialogService)
{
    _modalDialogService = modalDialogService;
    _modalDialogFactory = modalDialogFactory;
    _messageBoxService = messageBoxService;
    _fileDialogService = fileDialogService;
}
```

in App.xaml I don't use StartupUri.

At the moment in the App.xaml.cs I do the bootstraping manually:

```
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(new ModalDialogService(), new ModalDialogFactory(), new MessageBoxService(), new FileDialogService());
    mainWindow.Show();
```

I know I could use a container (like Unity) to do:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IModalDialogService, ModalDialogService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
/* ... and so on for each service interface and its appropriate implementation... */

MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.DataContext = container.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>();
mainWindow.Show();
```

In another question I learned that I could go maybe a step further and have the IModalDialogFactory implemented as an auto-factory and injected ...

**However I realized that I am missing one important thing:**

When I need those services in `TextFileProjectViewModel` and `SpreadsheetProjectViewModel`, that are being created in `MainWindowViewModel`, I need to manually inject the references into them.
I read somewhere that introducing the container into the `MainWindowViewModel` would be a bad thing from design point of view, as it creates an unnecessary dependency. 
However I don't know how I could use a DI container (any, not just Unity) to resolve the other viewmodels inside `MainWindowViewModel` without holding a reference inside the `MainWindowViewModel`.

Am I missing something or did I make a design / architectural mistake?

Comment: There's always corner cases with dependency injection. What we usually do is have a static properties, accessible from your library / application, referencing the container. Otherwise, your ViewModelA will need to have it's referenced view model's injectable property in its own class (and so on) and leads to more complication than anything. It's either that, or have a sort of `ViewModelLocator` service that you pass on the type and that will take care of creating the ViewModel with all dependencies injected for you.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize in advance for not knowing much in the xaml space, but hopefully this helps.

There are corner cases where you have to pick something other than proper DI. Best case is typically Constructor Injection.

*"Adhering strictly to Constructor Injection makes it easy to see when one violates the SRP and should refactor to an Facade Service."* - http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices

For those an abstract factory, reference to the DI container or a [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics) are the closest thing to decoupling I can think of.

[Service locator an anti pattern?](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern)

That said, what is constructing your `ViewModel` and can you push that dependency up far enough that your [DI composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot) is usable?

Comment: My ViewModels are constructed in MainWindowViewModel (I have a dockable "MDI"). MainWindowVM is constructed (as stated in OP) in App.xaml.cs in OnStartup() method. The App.OnStartup() method is also my Composition Root. | I think that the dependency that constructs my ViewModels (MainWindowVM) is already pushed into the composition root. | I don't know what you mean by DI Composition root to be usable? | I need more time to think about your answer as I am confused a little bit and I am working on different part of app atm. Maybe your edit will clarify things, if not I will update or comment.